# SQL запрос в opencart

Tags: sql, opencart

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно построить SQL-запрос? Есть таблица category и category_description. Нужно выбрать из category_description поля name и category_id где language_id = 1, а с таблицы category выбрать поле parent_id где category_id равен category_id с первой таблицы. 
    У меня что-то такое, но ничего не работает.

```
public function getAllCategories() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name, category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description WHERE language_id = '1' AS cd LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category AS c ON (c.parent_id = cd.category_id)");
    return $query->rows;
}
```

Comment: Что надо выводить для записей из `category`, не имеющих соответствия в таблице `category_description`? Что надо выводить для записей из `category_description`, не имеющих соответствия в таблице `category`?

Comment: @Akina у этих двух таблиц общее category_id, мне с таблицы category_description нужно вывести "name" и "category_id", а с таблицы category вывести parent_id для каждого "name" из category_description. В результате должен получиться двумерный массив, из которого можно для каждого "name" получить его category_id и parent_id, чтобы узнать является ли категория главной(если parent_id=0) или же она является подкатегорией (если parent_id не 0 ).

Comment: Вы не ответили на заданный вопрос.

Comment: @Akina, я конечно извиняюсь, может я неправильно понял Ваш вопрос, но мне кажется, что я очень подробно описал что мне надо сделать. Вот структура таблицы category : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `top` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `column` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: @Akina, а вот category_description : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_category_description` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `seo_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `seo_h1` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: *может я неправильно понял Ваш вопрос* Угу. В `oc_category` есть записи с `category_id=1` и `category_id=2`. В `oc_category_description` есть записи с `category_id=2` и `category_id=3`. Что нужно вывести? К тому же ни в одной из таблиц поле `category_id` не является уникальным - что нужно вывести, если имеется несколько записей с одним и тем же значением?

Comment: @Akina, category_id в обеих таблицах является первичным ключом, в дампе эта инфа находится просто в самом низу, поэтому я ее не скопировал.

Comment: @Akina ALTER TABLE `oc_category`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`);ALTER TABLE `oc_category_description`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`);

Comment: Ок, вторая часть сообщения снимается. Первая - остаётся. Это тоже вопрос, и тоже пока оставшийся без ответа...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function getAllCategories() {
    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT cd.name, cd.gategory_id, c.parent_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd 
        ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id)
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) 
        WHERE cd.language_id = 1 
        AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'     
        AND c.status = '1'";

    return $query->rows;
}
```

Не забывайте проверять активный магазин `c2s.store_id`(мало ли что) и статус категории на отображение `c.status`

Comment: да, спасибо большое, это оно)

Comment: P.S. исправьте опечатку.

Answer (score 0):

Так как с помощью одного запроса решить проблему на данный момент не удалось -
 решил исправить свою проблему с помощью двух запросов:

```
public function getAllCategories() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name, category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description WHERE language_id = '1'");
    return $query->rows;
}

public function getAllCategoriesParents() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT parent_id, category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category");
    return $query->rows;
}
```

А затем уже на php, с помощью цикла, в массив с именами добавлю parent_id по совпадению category_id в обоих массивах.